# Java HttpResponse Contains Excel File with Javascript in Contents

Tags: html, excel, jsoup, httpresponse

I'm downloading an excel file from a site, after posting data needed to generate the file's contents, I do this.

```
CloseableHttpResponse excelResponse = httpClient.execute(post);
InputStream in = excelResponse.getEntity().getContent();
File excel = new File("/myfiles/report.xls");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(excel);
try {
    IOUtils.copy(in, out);
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

The problem is, when I do this the excel file contains the final line:

```
$(window).ready(function() { runShowNotificationPopup(6); });
```

Which I suppose was part of the contents and is meant to popup the file dialog in a browser. 
Can I get just the attachment data from an `HttpResponse(Apache)`? If not, what are my options for removing this? `POI`? or is there some easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because the response messages content was an HTML table rather than an excel file. The javascript shown above was a legal part of that html and so when Excel tried to convert the HTML table to an Excel Spreadsheet, it pasted the above javascript on the last line.

The fix was to use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the HTML table into a csv.